# mapping data with a spike to a heat map

Tags: algorithms, dataset

I have the following data set that I need to display on the heat map:

```
[ 30, 15, 66, 7, 9999, 78, 42, 132 ]
```

So if I map the values to the color scale using a linear function I only see the spike while the rest of the values I cannot tell apart because the difference between them is insignificant in the scale of that spike.

I tried a log function but it didn't get a good looking picture either.

I don't care about accurate correspondence between the value and the color intensity.

Is there a way to map the values to the color scale so that the difference between all values was visible? Can I mitigate that spike somehow? I am asking about established approaches or algorithms addressing problems like this.

Comment: Consider mapping the data that is within N standard deviations of the mean to the heat map with special colors/symbols for the outliers.

Comment: You could try to renumber them by their position if you would sort them ([3,2,4,1,8,6,5,7]). If you get more distinct numbers than colors, you can combine multiple as one (either those whose value is close or log(value) is close (or some other function).

Comment: *Very* closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/how-to-find-a-suitable-association-of-color-with-data-value-in-a-visualization.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: I would have set a treshshold, computing another vector v such that vi= min(200, xi).

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways of handling outliers, as well as answers to similar questions here already. I would recommend taking a look at

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811866/ggplot2-color-scale-over-affected-by-outliers
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Working_with_outliers

The first deals with this problem in R. Taking the approach of graphing the non-outliers with a heatmap, then overlaying the outliers and annotating the legend to describe that this is what was done.

The second contains links to general solutions and approaches to outliers.